# How can two audioplayer play at same time?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I like to install two audioplayer on my WordPress page so that both players will playing at same time. So how is it possible to tell each player not to stop playing if an other player is running?

Thanks for helping out.

I just started to look for a plugin player.

Answer (score 0):

As per your description you have not mentioned about how do you want that page to load the audio. (For example to load those 2 audio on page load or user input/interactions with them.)

On WordPress you can add custom JS code or some hook to those elements or interaction event.

For easy go if you use on page load(as you have not described the way to interact with them) see if this helps you or if it leads you to any idea about way you want it to implement:

```
// just for example
function playAudio() {
   var audio1 = document.getElementById('audio1');
   var audio2 = document.getElementById('audio2');
   audio1.play();
   audio2.play();
}
```